# AngularJS Map Rendring & performance Issue

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I  implemented google Map with  cluster and polyline drawing with vehicle moving on it, and divided map functionality with time slots please check image to get clear understanding,

**My Main Problem** when large number of lat longs comes in response rendering get hanged for few seconds and also please wait loading (Some time get hanged), Sometimes also result in the no response with the page ,

Please help me with the solution[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDQGD.png)

[Map Image with buttons functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6vkE.png)

Comment: The first error in your js console is pretty important. You've included the google-maps-api js-file more than one time. Check your markup and find duplicate script tags - maybe it's even the solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for response i have removed the redundent map file but still slow

Comment: @MayankDwivedi can you provide a working sample?

Comment: No Sir it is production and i can not share details for them